# How to verify the gauge invariance of the term $\mathcal{L}= -\frac{1}{2}tr[(F^{i}_{\mu \nu}\sigma^i)^2]$?

Tags: tensor-calculus, gauge-theory, gauge-invariance, yang-mills

This is equation (15.38) from Peskin and Schroeder. I am unable to compute this term to verify if it is invariant (I know that it is but I'd like to verify that).
I would appreciate it if someone can guide me through the computation of $\mathcal{L}$ or can direct me towards a paper/book that does.

Some of the equations you might need the computation are:

$$F^{i}_{\mu \nu} = \partial_\mu A^i_\nu-\partial_\nu A^i_\mu + g\epsilon^{ijk}A^{j}_\mu A^{k}_\nu$$

while $\sigma^i$ being the Pauli matrices, with the following commutation relation:
$$\left[\frac{\sigma^i}{2},\frac{\sigma^j}{2}\right]=i\epsilon^{ijk}\frac{\sigma^k}{2}$$

I will also write the transformation of the field strength which I believe is not crucial for the computation of $\mathcal{L}$:

The transformation of the field strength is:

$$F^{i}_{\mu \nu}\frac{\sigma^i}{2}\rightarrow F^{i}_{\mu \nu}\frac{\sigma^i}{2} + \left[i\alpha^i\frac{\sigma^i}{2}, F^{j}_{\mu \nu}\frac{\sigma^j}{2}\right] $$

with :

$$ F^{i}_{\mu \nu}\frac{\sigma^i}{2}=\partial_\mu A^i_\nu \sigma^i-\partial_\nu A^i_\mu \sigma^i - ig[A^i _\mu \frac{\sigma^i}{2},A^j _\nu \frac{\sigma^j}{2}] $$

Comment: The $i$ and $j$ indices in the commutator (in the field strength tensor transformation) look wrong to me.

Comment: you're completely right ! thanks, i fixed them

Comment: You'll also need the Pauli matrices' anticommutators to verify this. (Do you know them?) A first-order change $\delta A$ in $A:=F^i_{\mu\nu}\sigma^i$ obeys the product rule$$\delta(A^2)=\delta(AA)=(\delta A)A+A\delta A=\{\delta A,\,A\}.$$

Comment: I don't think I know them but what I do know is that here "i" spans from 1 to 3

Comment: Can you write down what you have done so far for this calculation so we can guide you properly?

Comment: I replaced the term inside the trace using the equality in the last equation on my post, I squared it and tried to separate it into many trace terms. But again, the algebraic mess I got is not easily manipulatable. 
I am unable to understand the nature of the product between $F^i _{\mu \nu}$ and $\sigma^i$ as the first is a 4x4 matrix and the second is a 2x2. In addition, I am unable to comprehend how the trace would work on such a product . 
In the book they write it as if $\mathcal{L} is trivially found to be of this form (like in my question). But I am struggling to wrap my head around it

Comment: First of all, are you from Paris Saclay? Secondly, it would be better to write your steps by editing your post so everyone can see what you have done at first sight. $F^i_{\mu \nu}$ is not a $4 \times 4$ matrix, it is the $i,\mu,\nu$ component of the field strength $F$. Similarly, $\sigma^i$ is the ith component of $\vec{\sigma}$ and is as you said, a $2\times 2$ matrix.

Comment: Yes ! I am an M1 student at Paris-Saclay, an aspiring mathematical physicist :) . 
Thanks for the clarification regarding $F^i _{\mu \nu}$ . 
Indeed, I will write my steps on the post for further clarification.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your reply to @JeanbaptisteRoux shows you've overestimated how many nonzero commutators are present. In fact$$\left[i\alpha^i\frac{\sigma^i}{2},\,F_{\mu\nu}^j\frac{\sigma^j}{2}\right]=i\alpha^iF_{\mu\nu}^j\left[\frac{\sigma^i}{2},\,\frac{\sigma^j}{2}\right]=-\alpha^iF_{\mu\nu}^j\epsilon^{ijk}\frac{\sigma^k}{2},$$i.e. the change in $F_{\mu\nu}^i\sigma^i$ is $-\alpha^iF_{\mu\nu}^j\epsilon^{ijk}\sigma^k$. The reason you don't have to worry about $F_{\mu\nu}^i$ being a "matrix" is because its spacetime tensor indices $F_{\mu\nu}$ are irrelevant to $F\sigma$ etc. terms. The above calculation is really a separate only-Roman-indices-matter result for each pair $(\mu,\,\nu)$.

I mentioned before that first-order changes satisfy $\delta(A^2)=\{\delta A,\,A\}$. Therefore, the first-order change in $(F_{\mu\nu}^i\sigma^i)^2$ is$$\left\{F^{h\mu\nu}\sigma^h,\,-\alpha^iF_{\mu\nu}^j\epsilon^{ijk}\sigma^k\right\}=-F^{h\mu\nu}\alpha^iF_{\mu\nu}^j\epsilon^{ijk}\left\{\sigma^h,\,\sigma^k\right\}.$$When I did so, you explained you didn't know the value of $\left\{\sigma^h,\,\sigma^k\right\}$, which is $2\delta^{hk}I_2$ with $I_2$ the $2\times2$ matrix.

I think you can finish now.

Comment: Firstly, I want to thank you for persevering and helping me out ! 
I am unable to see how to proceed. ( My weakness is with computation) So I do know that the trace of the anticomutator $\left \{ F^{h \mu \nu}\sigma^h,-\alpha^i F^j _{\mu \nu} \epsilon^{ijk} \sigma^k \right \}$ should be zero so that the $\mathcal{L}$  would stay invariant under this transformation.  But my problem is with computing the terms and manipulating them. ( I hope I am not mistaken about the value of the trace of the anticommutator)

Comment: @CharbelAbetian It's not just traceless, it's a zero matrix. I might be helping too much now, but in the calculation$$-F^{h\mu\nu}\alpha^iF_{\mu\nu}^j\epsilon^{ijk}\left\{\sigma^h,\,\sigma^k\right\}=-2F^{h\mu\nu}\alpha^iF_{\mu\nu}^j\epsilon^{ijk}\delta^{hk}I_2=-2\alpha^i\underbrace{F^{h\mu\nu}F_{\mu\nu}^j}_{+}\underbrace{\epsilon^{ijh}}_{-}I_2,$$the quantity with a $\pm$ underbrace multiplies by $\pm1$ under $h\leftrightarrow j$.

Comment: Oh, okay thank you a lot ! 
Then why the need for the trace of $(F^i _{\mu \nu} \sigma^i)^2 $ in the $\mathcal{L}$ and not $(F^i _{\mu \nu} \sigma^i )^2 $ ? Is it simply because we only want scalar quantities in  $\mathcal{L}$ ?

Comment: @CharbelAbetian That's exactly it.

Comment: Not all heroes wear capes ! Some of them are really good at maths! Thanks a lot you made my day, I wish you a great rest of the week sir !